# stats::mad gone mad?

Tags: r, statistics

First time using `mad()` Median Absolute Deviation on a vector, mostly 4 and 5, some `NA`.
Am I mistaken, but why would the `mad` function not return a positive value for

```
mad(c(4,5,5,5))
```

? Instead, I get a 0.
I would only expect 0 if all values in the vector are the same, not if there is variation in value.

Please enlighten me. I am using R version 4.05.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation the function will return the "median of the absolute deviations from the median"

So in the case of

```r
x <- c(4,5,5,5)
```

The median is

```r
median(x)
# [1] 5
```

and the differences are

```r
x-median(x)
# [1] -1  0  0  0
```

which have absolute value

```r
abs(x-median(x))
# [1] 1 0 0 0
```

And the median value of the vector is just 0

```r
median(abs(x-median(x)))
[1] 0
```

It seems your expectation is just off. You don't get 0 only when all values are the same, you can get 0 when the median difference is 0. That happens when more than half of your values are actually the median value. Another vector that returns 0 is

```r
mad(c(1, 7, 7, 7, 100))
[1] 0
```

Comment: I see that my wronged median expectations were driving me insane. Thanx for helping me to learn und understand this deviation measure.